# Computing differences between all combinations of matrix columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations, vectorization, bsxfun

I have about 1000 columns of data. I want to create another array comprising the differences between all possible combinations of the columns for all rows of data. I can go about it using a`for` loop, but is there an easier way in MATLAB to do this?

Data is in the following format

```
Date Col1 Col2 ..... Col1000
.     .   .              . 
.     .   .              .
```

I need the final array to be in the following format

```
Date Col1-Col2 Col1-Col3 .... Col1-Col1000 Col2-Col3 Col2-Col4 ..... Col2-Col1000
```

and continuing to `Col999-Col1000` for a total of `nchoosek(1000,2)+1` columns of data plus the dates.

Comment: all possible combination means also `Col2-Col1, Col2-Col2` etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bsxfun` can virtually replicate in *more than one* dimension, allowing you to avoid a loop (sorry naysayers and bitter down-voters, it's true):

```
P = 50; N = 1000; A = rand(P,N);

% bsxfun for singleton expansion: 50x1000x1 @minus 50x1x1000 => 50x1000x1000
B = bsxfun(@minus,A,permute(A,[1 3 2]));
B = reshape(-B,size(A,1),[]);
```

That gives a `P-by-N*N` matrix which provides *all* the combinations.  To get the thinned out (i.e. with `sum(1:N-1)` columns) matrix:

```
m = logical(tril(ones(N),-1)); % lower triangular logical not including diagonal
B = B(:,m(:));
```

Finally, concatenate the dates to get what you need:

```
C = [dates B];
```

Comment: for generality, please replace `50` with the proper dimension of A (size(A,1)) in the 3rd line...

Comment: Thanks.  I have to remind my self to think about higher dimensions to exploit `bsxfun` this way.

Comment: How do you pick out the differences in the way that the question specifies?

Comment: @Nirk - Sort of like you did, only different.  ;)  See my updated answer.

Comment: Any comments from the two completely different people who downvoted, simultaneously by complete coincidence?  Something wrong?

Comment: Beautiful.  I would have never thought `bsxfun` could work with multiple singleton dimensions.  Ignore the downvoters.  They don't know what they're downvoting!

Comment: @chappjc - I was wondering.... this comment stream seems disconnected. Now it makes total sense. Talk about being so unprofessional lol.  If I was proven wrong and wrote an answer, I would have left it up anyway so that other people could learn that even though many people would think one way (i.e. using a `for` loop was the only possible way), there was still a way around it (i.e. using `bsxfun` over multiple singleton dimensions).

Comment: @chappjc - Oh yes.  I didn't bother scrolling down because your answer was all I needed to read lol.  I also scrolled and saw natan delete his answer.  I'm amazed how it got a downvote because it was a legitimate answer.  My guess is SheetJS downvoted because natan's answer is much simpler even with a loop.  SheetJS's answer looks rather complicated and I can spot places where some computation is unnecessary.  In any case, I feel you about this.  My first experience with a sock puppet was that answer using `find/len` to find the number of non-zero numbers. I'm sure you remember that answer!

Comment: @chappjc - On that sock puppet note, that bogus answer got recently deleted by a mod, and I'm glad it did.  The use of `find` and `len` to find the number of non-zero numbers in a matrix has so much computational overhead and telling people that it's an accepted answer starts to make you doubt everything you knew about MATLAB.... but it being gone has brought balance to the universe lol.

Comment: @rayryeng Hurray for justice on the bogus `find`/`length` answer - that had to go!  And yes, SheetJS's answer was fine, and much more memory efficient than mine but I just had to demonstrate how it could be done.  :) and he didn't like that   :D

Comment: @chappjc - Yikes... I spelled it as `len` and not `length` lol.  Did a lot of Python today so still in that mindset.  I never use it and only use `numel`.  I've paid homage to your profile message.  BTW, if it were me, I would have upvoted your answer (I did upvote btw) and said kudos because it was something I would have never thought possible.  It's nice to be proven wrong once in a while, and this is a great example.